# Multiple join query and sub query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Table Structures:
**tblCustomer**

```
Customer_id  created                 field1            field2        cardno       field14
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
1014         2010-05-25 12:51:59.547 Cell Phone        abc@lmn.com   1234567890   Test Card
1015         2010-08-15 12:51:59.547 Email             abc@xyz.com   2345678891   NULL
```

**tbl_TransactionDishout**

```
Trnx_id   offerNo   TerminalID      Created                  VirtualCard
-------------------------------------------------------------------
1         1014      170924690436418 2010-05-25 12:51:59.547  1234567890
```

Relation between tbl_transaction and tblCustomer is having same cardno.
Is it possible to get the result as below date-wise records:

```
               Enrolled   Enrolled as Email  Enrolled as Text Deals Redeemed   
<First Date>   7          5                  2                6
<Next Date>    9          3                  6               14
```

Date should be from both tables even if it has zero records..

```
Enrolled          - Total No of records that is summation of Enrolled as Email and Enrolled as Text.      
Enrolled as Email - Where field1 = 'Email' from tblCustomer table
Enrolled as Text  - Where field1 = 'cell phone' from tblCustomer table
Deals Redeemed    - Where field14 <> 'Test Card' from tblCustomer table and    
                    where DishoutResponsecode = '0000' from tbl_Transaction table
```

My Existing Query:

```
SELECT
convert(varchar, CAST(ISNULL(t1.created,t2.created) AS DATETIME), 111) created,
COUNT(CASE WHEN (t1.field1 = 'E-mail' or t1.field1 = 'Cell Phone')  and (t1.field14 <>  'Test Card'  or t1.field14 is null) THEN 1 END) Enrolled,
COUNT(CASE WHEN t1.field1 = 'E-mail'            and (t1.field14 <> 'Test Card'   and t1.field14 is null) THEN 1 END) Enrolled_as_Email,
COUNT(CASE WHEN t1.field1 = 'Cell Phone'        and (t1.field14 <> 'Test Card'   and t1.field14 is null) THEN 1 END) Enrolled_as_Cell,
COUNT(CASE WHEN t2.DishoutResponseCode = '0000' and (IsNull(t1.field14, '') <> 'Test Card') THEN 1 END) Deals_Redeemed  
FROM  tblCustomer AS t1
FULL OUTER JOIN
      tbl_TransactionDishout t2
ON  t1.cardno = t2.VirtualCard and t1.created = t2.created
GROUP BY
      convert(varchar, CAST(ISNULL(t1.created,t2.created) AS DATETIME),      111)
ORDER BY
      convert(varchar, CAST(ISNULL(t1.created,t2.created) AS DATETIME), 111) DESC
```

**Last 4-5 records in tblCustomer table**

```
created                 cardno               field14
----------------------------------------------------------
2012-03-07 10:03:00.034 1234007600101240    
2012-03-05 04:02:00.040 1234007600602122    
2012-03-01 06:25:50.400 1234010400972168     Test Card
2012-03-01 30:05:30.022 555566669999         Test Card
2012-03-01 50:50:20.450 666677778888         Test Card
```

**Last 4-5 records in tbl_TransactionDisout table**

```
created                 VirtualCard         DishoutResponseCode
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
2012-03-09 13:18:02.703 1234010400972168    0010
2012-03-09 13:17:35.307 1234010400972168    0002
2012-03-09 13:17:14.237 1234010400972168    0007
2012-03-09 13:16:57.650 1234010400972168    0002
2012-03-08 21:13:57.137 1234010400475686    0000
2012-03-08 16:50:38.273 1234010400972168    0002
2012-03-08 16:50:26.070 1234010400972168    0007
2012-03-08 16:49:49.793 1234010400972168    0002
```

So there is only one card in this with having response code '0000' and also not a 'Test Card'..But I am getting all the card with code = '0000' and also having 'Test Card' so that means field14 is not able to compare because it is from the different table and different date..

Comment: This is the probably the third day that you ask the same question. Why do you start a new question every day?

Comment: Because I am not getting a response what I want @Jaques

Comment: What is the layout of the tbl_TransactionDishout table, because you specify DishoutResponseCode, but you don't show it at the top. The second this is, is the <First Date> and <Second Date> the date excluding the time? So you want to group it per day?

Comment: And which date should be used. Should the two tables link on the date as well. Should the dates be be for a full day? The question is very vaque, that is propably why you don't get an answer

Comment: Yes...They are the date with the time also..but we want to check against the date only not the time..@Jaques

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the result I get back with this query when I use the data that you specified in the main question:

```
SELECT  
  convert(varchar, CAST(ISNULL(t1.created,t2.created) AS DATETIME), 111) created,  
  COUNT(CASE WHEN (t1.field1 = 'Email' or t1.field1 = 'Cell Phone')  and (t1.field14 <> 'Test Card'  or t1.field14 is null) THEN 1 END) Enrolled,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN t1.field1 = 'Email'            and (IsNull(t1.field14, '') <> 'Test Card') THEN 1 END) Enrolled_as_Email,  
  COUNT(CASE WHEN t1.field1 = 'Cell Phone'        and (IsNull(t1.field14, '') <> 'Test Card') THEN 1 END) Enrolled_as_Cell,  
  COUNT(CASE WHEN t2.DishoutResponseCode = '0000' and (IsNull(t1.field14, '') <> 'Test Card') THEN 1 END) Deals_Redeemed  
FROM  
  tblCustomer AS t1  
FULL OUTER JOIN  
  tbl_TransactionDishout t2  
    ON  t1.cardno = t2.VirtualCard  
    AND t1.created = t2.created  
GROUP BY  
  convert(varchar, CAST(ISNULL(t1.created,t2.created) AS DATETIME), 111)  
ORDER BY  
  convert(varchar, CAST(ISNULL(t1.created,t2.created) AS DATETIME), 111) DESC
```

Result:

```
created                        Enrolled    Enrolled_as_Email Enrolled_as_Cell Deals_Redeemed
------------------------------ ----------- ----------------- ---------------- --------------
2012/03/09                     0           0                 0                0
2012/03/08                     0           0                 0                1
2012/03/07                     1           0                 1                0
2012/03/05                     1           0                 1                0
2012/03/01                     0           0                 0                0
```

Comment: Now..it showing all rows where DishoutResponsecode = '0000' but not checking the field14 in tblcustomer...    
So the problem I found is this: The field14 will be checked where the date is also from the tblCustomer table..so the corss check is not working..@Jaques

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by its not checking the field14 in tblcustomer. if is specified in the code correct? Maybe you should post your query that you using again. Will the created fields always be the same in tblCusomer and tbl_TransactionDishout? Can you add some extra data as well, because I've created it on my side to test.

Comment: @VishalSuthar I used that query on my tables that I've created now, and I get the expected results. Please give me some data that doesn't produce the expected results, then I can see what is wrong.

Comment: I have edited the main question and added more information which will help you..@Jaques

Comment: Above is my results. Do you want the 1 at the Deals_Redeemed to be in the 2012/03/07 Row?

Comment: But on my Live data it is showing all the card having response code = '0000' even if it is a 'Test Card'

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8848/discussion-between-vishal-suthar-and-jaques)